# Compression in Python 3.5, an integer is required (got type str)

Tags: python, python-3.x, compression

Im trying to make a program that allows the user to input data to specify the file name and extension and then compress that file and allow them to name it. However I keep getting the error message "An integer is required (Got type str), it says it has something to do with the 'rb' spot. Any info on how to fix this?

```
import zlib
first_answer = input("Please input file name")
print(first_answer)
second_answer = input("Please input file extension")
with open(first_answer, ".", second_answer, 'rb') as in_file:
compressed = zlib.compress(in_file.read(), 9)
third_answer = input("What would you like to call this new file?")

with open(third_answer, "wb") as out_file:
out_file.write(compressed)

print("File has been compressed!")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing in several *separate arguments* to the `open()` function:

```
with open(first_answer, ".", second_answer, 'rb') as in_file:
```

The 3rd positional argument to the `open()` function is the `buffer` argument which always must be an integer if specified.

You need to concatenate those strings with `+` or use string formatting to make it one argument instead:

```
with open(first_answer + "." + second_answer, 'rb') as in_file:
```